# Changing var value in jQuery

Tags: jquery

So, I have the following js:

```
var add_form = '0'; 
jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.click', function(e) {   
    if(add_form !== 1) {  ???????       
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: custom.ajax_url, 
            dataType: 'html',
            data: ({ action: 'get_form'}),
            success: function(data){
                    jQuery('.show_form').html(data);                        
                    add_form = '1';           
        });
    }   
});
```

The idea is that, if the var `add_form` is 0, then run the ajax script and add the form `data` in the `<div class="show_form">`. At the same time, change the `add_form` value to `1`, so that if the same `"click"` class is clicked, then it does not run the ajax script again (ie. only load the form once).

Do I have the form right?

Thanks

Comment: nope. lol I can see that the `add_form` value does change to 1 (checked it by `alert(add_form)`, but I still get the form when the button is clicked.

Comment: Problem is there is a time between the click and the ajax call that the user can click multiple times since you wait until the Ajax call is complete. And `1 !== "1"` types matter when you use a type comparison.

Comment: @j08691 - why do you ask, it clearly is wrong.

Comment: Why not just use jQuery's `.one()` function?

Comment: @Hogan - Because the OP said "Do I have the form right?"

Comment: Can you show me how to implement `.one()` function? I am curious to see. Also @Hogan pointed out that one var had character while another had number. The issue is fixed.

Comment: You're also missing a closing } for the success function in the provided example code.

Comment: Just change `.on()` to `.one()`. The `.one()` function only executes the code within it once. http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: @j08691 - `.one()` is cool, but he probably wants to re-enable the button after a change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't have it right

In one place you use the number one:

```
add_form !== 1
```

and in the other you use the character 1

```
add_form = '1';
```

Use the same thing in both places and it will work better I expect.

You also want to make the change right away instead of waiting for the async call to return -- you could use a different value for that (to show "running")

```
var add_form = 0; 
jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.click', function(e) {   
    if(add_form == 0) {  ???????       
        add_form = 2;
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: custom.ajax_url, 
            dataType: 'html',
            data: ({ action: 'get_form'}),
            success: function(data){
                    jQuery('.show_form').html(data);                        
                    add_form = 1;           
        });
    }   
});
```

Comment: Also thank you for the suggestion. It makes sense to change the value right away. =)

Comment: Just a little more information in case it helps, `==` tests values that can evaluate to each other so `'1' == 1` is `true` while `===` tests values that are identical so `'1' === 1` is `false`.  For the most part `===` (and it's companion `!==`) are consistent with other languages, while `==` and `!=` are more flexible.

Comment: @JasonSperske Thank you for the insightful info. I will keep that in mind =)

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
var add_form = '0'; 

$(document).on('click', '.click', function(e) {   
    if(!Number(add_form)) {     
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: custom.ajax_url, 
            dataType: 'html',
            data: ({ action: 'get_form'}),
            success: function(data){
                    jQuery('.show_form').html(data);                        
                    add_form = '1';           
        });
    }   
});
```